# Оптимизация запроса SQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте!

Имеется чат, соответственно имеются две таблицы `users` и `messages`. По значению автоинкремента видно, что сообщений более 800 000, пользователей - более 11 000 (уникальность пользователей определяется составным индексом `username-ip`).

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userid` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `msg` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=897235 ;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_ip` (`username`,`ip`),
  KEY `usernames` (`username`),
  KEY `ips` (`ip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=11956 ;
```

Уже голова пухнет, подскажите, как оптимизировать следующий запрос, одна проблема запрос должен быть только один, дабы не менять логику скрипта далее (кратко: необходимо выбрать все сообщения пользователя по его IP и естественно вывести к ним еще и его ники и адреса):

```
SELECT `t2`.`id` as `Number`, inet_ntoa(`t1`.`ip`)  as `IP`, 
       `t1`.`username` as `Nick`, `t2`.`msg` as `Message`
   FROM `messages` as `t2`
   LEFT JOIN `users` as `t1` ON `t2`.`userid` = `t1`.`id` 
   WHERE `t1`.`ip` = inet_aton('11.11.11.11')
   ORDER BY `t2`.`id`
```

Соответственно, лимитирование данных запроса не помогает, придумать другую структуру запроса не могу, то-ли мозг не варит, то-ли знания затерялись. Но чую, что где-то я что-то упустил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это достаточно очевидное решение, так что я, скорее всего, что-то упускаю, но все же:

```
select `t2`.`id` as `Number`, inet_ntoa(`t1`.`ip`)  as `IP`, 
`t1`.`username` as `Nick`, `t2`.`msg` as `Message` 
from users `t1` 
inner join messages `t2` on (t2.userid = t1.id AND t1.ip=inet_aton('11.11.11.11'))
order by `t2`.`id`;
```

**UPD.** А как насчет добавить индекс на `messages`.`userid`?

Comment: Те же 6-8 секунд на выборку. Даже, у меня складывается впечатление, что на пару секунд дольше стало.

Comment: Я пробовал составной индекс на `id-userid`, сейчас попробую проиндексировать

Comment: Блин, вот это вчера меня глюкануло добавить составной индекс с уникальным полем. Спасибо, теперь и мои 4 запроса летают.